# Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication RequiredUnable to establish SSL connection

Tags: proxy, ssl, tunnel

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/mseknibilel/OpenStack-Grizzly-Install-Guide/master/KeystoneScripts/keystone_basic.sh

--2014-03-05 12:55:27--  https://raw.github.com/mseknibilel/OpenStack-Grizzly-Install-Guide/master/KeystoneScripts/keystone_basic.sh
Resolving proxy4.xxxxx.com (proxy4.xxxxx.com)... 10.201.51.54
```

Connecting to proxy4.xxxxx.com (proxy4.xxxxx.com)|10.201.51.54|:8080... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: Proxy Authentication RequiredUnable to establish SSL connection.

Could someone let me know, where and in which file I need to set proxy password and user to get `wget` working?.

Answer (score 4):

Your proxy requires authentication. You need to use the `--proxy-user` and `--proxy-password` parameters of `wget` to provide the authentication credentials.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to set the **proxy** for the **wget**. Edit your `~/.wgetrc` to add;

```
use_proxy=yes
http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port>
https_proxy=https://<user>:<password>@<ip>:<port>
```

Read [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11211812/4361073)

Comment: Please add a short explanation and add the link only for reference.